# Include Does not work in my Class Definition

Tags: php, oop

Here is the class definition

```
class SimpleUserLogin
{
  private $dbc;
  private $db;

  public function __construct($dbc) //variable: DB connect resource
  {
    //load constants
    include("config.php");
    ----
    ----
```

And here is the Config.php

```
<?php
//define("DBNAME", "test");
    $d = "Why Are You Not Working";
    echo $d;
?>
```

And here is the code instantiating the Class. It is another FILE

```
$sul = new SimpleUserLogin($con);
```

As you can see, i was defining a Constant before. But when it was not working i decided to just echo a variable in the included config.php file. And yet when i instantiate an object from this class, nothing gets printed!

What am i doing wrong? :(

**UPDATE**
I edit the "config.php" code to become a CLASS definition instead of just a list of defined constants. And in my SimpleUserLogin i tried creating an object from the config CLASS in the __constructor function this way:

```
$bee = new Config();
echo $bee->dbname;
```

I get the following error

> Notice: Undefined property: Config::$dbname in
>   C:\wamp\www\SimpleUserLogin\SimpleUserLogin.php on line 16

**What am i doing wrong?** :(

**UPDATE**
I renamed the 'config.php' to 'configx.php' and everything works!!! Now that is super strange! anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: Please include the code that instantiate the object from this class

Comment: I do not understand. Can you show some more code?

Comment: The Instantiating code is simple...its simple 
$sul = new SimpleUserLogin($con);

Comment: try $test = include 'config.php' and then echo $test (you should get a warning if it fails)

Comment: posting the complete code will help others to identify the problem

Comment: @Exupery i tried what you suggested but when i echo $test, i get "1" :( guess this just means that the 'config.php' was included, but it does not solve the problem of why the things defined in config.php is not being carried into the class that is including the file :(

Comment: Is your config.php formatted as a PHP file? E.g. <?php ... ?>

Comment: Have you tried return $d instead of echo $d

Comment: OK, now you just need to glue the last piece -- please include the Config.php

Comment: @Exupery it is not even about the echo. In fact the CLASS does not need to echo what is defined in the Config.php file. It is meant to use the variables defined in the Config.php file. But when i include the CONSTANT defined in the Config.php file, it says the constants are not defined. I only use echo to understand what was going on and as it turns out, the ECHO itself is not working :( So something is wrong with the INCLUDE statement. It seems the INCLUDE statement fails in the CLASS. Which is strange :(

Comment: The include statement is not failing, you tested yourself and got 1 when echoing $test where $test = include 'config.php'
The return value of 1 indicates a successful include, so the problem is within your config.php file.  As others have requested you should post the entire contents of the config.php file.

Comment: @EXupery what i posted is actually all i have in "config.php" file for now:
<?php
//define("DBNAME", "test");
$d = "Why Are You Not Working";
echo $d;
?>

Comment: **UPDATE** I renamed the 'config.php' to 'configx.php' and everything works!!! Now that is super strange! anybody have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling that constructor anywhere?

You should need `$instance = new SimpleUserLogin($con);`

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
$sul = new SimpleUserLogin($con);
```

inside `config.php`, you are instantiating the class inside its own constructor. That isn't possible.